# Refresh sdcard in android

Tags: android

I have a mass storage device that when I write on a sector, it does something on this sector and write on it again. I wrote a program in Android that writes on mass storage device's sectors, but when sector was changed, the value in the file does not change. I want to refresh my mass storage device so that changes are visible. 
*I am sorry about my bad grammar, I am Iranian and I can't speak English well*

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue.. Please try this..

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

or

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))`);

or you can refer this link also..

[SD card files updated programmatically are not updated in windows explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592402/sd-card-files-updated-programmatically-are-not-updated-in-windows-explorer)

Hope this might help you..

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,i try this but not change my file on device. I try mount and unmount programmatically and work it but speed is important for me and i problem with his speed . i want otherthing with high speed

Comment: Have you try this code??  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile (this, new String[] {file.toString()}, null, null);   Add this line before sendBroadcast method.. it might work..

Comment: this not work for me , i change sector and scan file with this code but not change my file